# Excel IF Formula Getting AN "Entered Too Many Arguments" Error Message

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to plug in this formula into excel, however, I'm getting an error message stating that I have `entered too many arguments`

The equation is

```
=IF((G19-10.64)>=3,"1",IF(AND(G19-10.64)>=2.0,(G19-10.64)<=2.9),"2")
```

The cell G19 equates to 11.26.

So, if the sum of `11.26-10.64` is greater than or equal to `3`, give it a label of `"1"`, however, if the sum of `11.26-10.64` is between `2.0` and `2.9` give it a `"2"`.

Comment: The second "IF" statement is missing a piece. You have "if the sum is >=2.0, sum<=2.9". You don't tell the if statement what to do if >=2.0 is true.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
=IF((G19-10.64)>=3,"1",IF(AND((G19-10.64)>=2,(G19-10.64)<=2.9),"2","IF ELSE HERE"))
```

Replace "IF ELSE HERE" for what you want if neither of the conditions are met.